# Strands Like Hair in Fermenting Beer

Tags: fermentation, contamination, primary-fermentation

I am brewing a schwarzbier using US-05 because I don't have a setup to brew a real lager. The OG was 1.047 and I have a current gravity reading of 1.012 after 5 days of decent fermentation at an ambient temp of 65 degrees with an expected FG of 1.008 or so. The beer tastes like I expected, smells fine, and is still bubbling in the airlock. My only concern is a weird string like structure I noticed in the fermenter today. I've been scouring the Internet looking for something that resembles it but I have thus far been out of luck. Does this look familiar to anyone?

Here is a link to the recipe I based this off of, in case that helps: https://www.atlanticbrewsupply.com/assets/images/PDF/ABS%20RBC%20The%20Royal%20Lager%20AG.pdf

[image: FermenterPic]

Comment: It seems like it could be something similar to this: https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10173/interesting-formation-in-fermenting-beer?rq=1

But that wasn't answered super well, as far as I could tell.

Comment: I'm guessing: some (upside-down) plant material that came in from the hops, or on previous brew.  Do you have kids?  We once found a sandwich that had been "posted" into the VCR.  The low pH, low Oxygen and high ethanol environment has probably already out-competed any infection hazards.

Comment: Could be plant material, for sure. I brew outside and it is Spring in the Northern hemisphere. Kid theory isn't impossible, but seemingly unlikely. My main bummer about this is I wanted to use the yeast cake for a stout, but I guess I'll clean up and just make a starter.